# Is write to SOCK_SEQPACKET atomic?

Tags: linux, ipc, atomic, socketpair

What I mean atomic is success or failed and do nothing.

I know `socketpair(AF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM)` is not atomic, if multiple processes/threads call `write(fd, buf, len)`, the return value of the `write()` maybe `> 0 && < len` and cause data out of order.

If multiple processes/threads `write(buf, len)` to a `sock_fd` which created by `socketpair(AF_LOCAL, SOCK_SEQPACKET)`, is it atomic?

I check the Linux manual and found something about `pipe()` which says if the `len` is less than `PIPE_BUF`, the `write/writev` is atomic.

I found nothing about `socketpair`. I wrote a test code and found it seems that the `SOCK_SEQPACKET` is atomic, I write random length buffer to `fd` and the return value is always `-1` or `len`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Any interface that is datagram based (i.e. - the size you pass to `write` is visible to the person doing the `read`) must be atomic. There is no other way to guarantee that property.

So `SOCK_SEQPACKET`, as well as `SOCK_DGRAM`, must be atomic in order to function.

For that very same reason, `SOCK_STREAM` has no such atomicy guarantees.